# How to remove Specific Node is Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, nodes

I am trying to delete the specific Node but I don't see where the problem is.

Actually, I get the Node through the `Find()` and then delete it with `Remove()`.

The program crashes whenever `Delete()` fires.

```
bool RemoveNode(int key)
{
    if (IsEmpty())
        return false;
    Node* r = Find(key,root);
    if (r==nullptr)
        return false;
    return Remove(r);
}
bool Remove (Node* &r)
{
    if (r->left==nullptr && r->right ==nullptr)
    {
        delete r;
        r=nullptr;
        return true;
    }
    if (r->left==nullptr)
    {
        Node* temp = r->right;
        delete r;
        r=nullptr;
        r=temp;
        return true;
    }
    if (r->right==nullptr)
    {
        Node* temp = r->left;
        delete r;
        r=nullptr;
        r=temp;
        return true;
    }
    Node* Max = FindMax(r->left);
    r->data = Max->data;
    Remove(Max);

    return true;
}
Node* FindMax(Node* r)
{
    if(r->right==nullptr)
        return r;
    return FindMax(r->right);
}
Node* Find(int key, Node* &r)
{
    if (r==nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    if (r->data==key)
        return r;

    if (key < r->data)
        return Find(key,r->left);
    else
        return Find(key,r->right);
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to update the "parent" to no longer point to the deleted child node?

Comment: have you used a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, your `Remove()` function is intended to modify the pointer to the node, independent on where it is located: instead of passing in the raw pointer, you are passing in a reference to the pointer. This way, you could update the tree's `root` pointer, the `left` or `right` as a component of the next. As long as you pass it in the correct reference, I think the code should work.

The variable `r` is actually modified in `Remove()` which is a local variable defined in `RemoveNode()`: the result of `Find()` is a pointer, not a reference to the relevant pointer. However, you need to modify the pointer in your tree structure pointing to the node, not an arbitrary local variable.

The fix would be the use a special version of `Find()' which correctly returns a reference to the pointer rather than the pointer itself. Your recursive`Find()`would be up to the task if it returned a`Node*&`rather than a`Node*`. Since your tree doesn't seem to be balanced and stack space is relatively limited, I'd rather use a non-recursive function. Instead of returning a reference to a pointer it would maintain a pointer to a pointer to the current node instead of a pointer to the node:

```
Node** InternFind(int key) {
    Node** n = &this->root;
    while (*n && (*n)->key != key) {
        n = &(key < (*n)->key? (*n)->left: (*n)->right);
    }
    return n;
}
```

The code is untested and probably not quite right. Once you got the pointer to the pinter, however, you can just update it without dealing with where the came from:

```
Node** r = InternFind(key);
if (*r) {
    Remove(*r);
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Although I don't know what "if `Delete()` fires" means, I'd assume you have a problem with duplicate uses of `delete p` for the same pointer `p`. The code probably goes wrong long before that accessing stale nodes.

Comment: `r` is actually `Node* &r`, so changing it correctly changes the passed-in parameter.  Justin identified the real problem: child pointers not being updated in the parent after `Remove()` is called.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Thanks for the downvote but given that `r` is defined as `Node* r = Find(key,root);` the fact that it is passed as a reference when using `Remove(r);` doesn't really help. Admittedly, the function where it is defined is `RemoveNode()` rather than `Remove()`, however (I edited the answer on a mobile phone which makes it hard to keep track of the exact details). The point is: if the correct reference were passed in (which you'd do, e.g., by locating the pointer to pointer to the node and then dereferencing it), you'd update the pointer in the parent!

Comment: I see what you mean.  Another way (equivalent to your `InternFind()` I think) would be just changing the return type of `Find()` to `Node*&` -- a reference is as good as a pointer.  (It looks like the OP might have been going for something like this, what with the otherwise inexplicable `Node* &r` parameter to `Find()`).  If you clarify what's going on with the reference in your answer, I'll +1.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I updated the description and added a comment on why I'd prefer a non-recursive version of `Find()` (and, yes, I realize that the function is tail-recursive but there is no requirement for C++ compilers to eliminate tail-recursion).